# syntax error in my foreach loop as it looks through an Array of int Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, foreach, compiler-errors

So, I have an array that contains four int arrays, I also have an int array that holds player input. I want to compare the player Input array against each of the int Arrays within the first Array. It was recommended to use a foreach loop however I cannot get it to work, this is what it looks like at the moment:

```
foreach(int[] i in spellList[i][])
        {
          Debug.Log("One Array");
        }
```

So as I understand it it is saying for every int array in spellList[in the first array][] print `One Array` in the console.

I would also like to use the local variable `i` to compare it against another array which in theory should be simple as I can just say `if(i = inputArray)` as it runs the foreach however I can't get that far.

Thanks and sorry if this seems simple I'm just getting into loops that aren't just the update function!

**Edit:**

So having resolved the syntax error and changing my code to the code below I have a new issue, it just isn't responding, I know it should as I have debugged it multiple times through the console:

```
foreach(int[] i in spellList)
        {
            if (spellCapture == i)
            {
                Debug.Log("match");
            }

        }
```

Now i know that at least once the array of ints i is equal to the stored array of ints that takes user input in spellCapture but it wont run the debug.log...

Comment: you can't use "i" in your "spellList[i][]" statement.Because "i" is an array,and in "spellList[?][]" -> "?" require an integer

Comment: Ah thank you very much! So if I want to access the current iteration how would I go about doing so?

Comment: if you are new try use "for" loop first then use foreach.And also you have syntax error.You need only write "spellList" instead of "spellList[i][]".And for more see nested foreach.See here http://www.eidias.com/blog/2014/6/10/nested-foreach-loops-replacement-in-c

Comment: Okay, i'll take a look at that now. I think I know my way around the foreach loop now, it is working like it should but I cannot access i with an if statement, it isn't an error but it's not giving me a response in the console when it should, I'll edit the main post with the code. Thanks again for taking the time!

Comment: An array is a reference type, so comparing with == checks if they are exactly the same array, not two arrays with same values. You can use the LINQ method SequenceEquals, or use another loop to compare the contents of your array, which bring ints, are value types, so == will work as you expect

Comment: Ah! That's it. Thanks, I'll look into this SequenceEquals although i'll also have to look into what LINQ is as well. I had been trying to work out how I would compare the individual elements as well so I think I'll try to get both methods working for the sake of learning. Which method do you think is more efficient/useful?

Comment: The loop will help you understand better what is happening under the covers but I find Linq to be more expressive, which is an important part of "clean code". However, because you are writing code for Unity3d, you need to know that the old implementation of Linq used by Unity has some performance issues. For that reason, you might want to end up sticking with the loop.

Comment: ok I'll bare that in mind, I could use more experience learning the loops so I'll stick with that, Thanks for the help!